# $(2p-x-y)^2 = 4xy+1$ and $2p-x-y = 2m+1$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $x,y,p,$ and $m$ be positive integers such that $(2p-x-y)^2 = 4xy+1$ and $2p-x-y = 2m+1$. Prove that if $m = dh$ and $x = dk$ where $d = \gcd(m,x)$, then $m+1 = gk$ and $y = gh$ where $g = \gcd(m+1,y)$.

This seemed like a complicated statement to prove and so I wasn't sure how to go about proving  it. Would proving it by contradiction work or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
From first two identities, you have
\begin{align*}
(2p-x-y)^2 &=(2m+1)^2 \\
&=4m^2+4m+1\\
&=4xy+1
\end{align*}
So you have $m^2+m=xy$. Then you can write:
\begin{align*}
m^2+m &= xy \\
(m+1)dh &= dky \\
(m+1)h &= ky
\end{align*}
Therefore you have $\frac{m+1}{y} = \frac{k}{h}$ where $h,k$ are relatively prime. Hence you should have 
$$
m+1 = \gcd(m+1,y)k, \quad y = \gcd(m+1,y)h
$$

Comment: Why does $m^2+m = xy$?

Comment: Included more explanation